# Magento 2 rating add custom filter add in product page review tab

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, php-7, review

i need a filter review by name or date and by sort in magento 2.3
product review tab , so customer can easily search best review how can implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free extension available and use it accordingly.
https://landofcoder.com/advanced-magento-2-product-reviews.html

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the code to sort review.**

This code is for sort by ratings.

```
$countColumn = new \Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT(*)");
$percentColumn = new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(percent)/".$countColumn );

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
   ['rating_vote'=>$this->_reviewsCollection->getTable('rating_option_vote')],
   'rating_vote.review_id=main_table.review_id',
   ['sum' => 'SUM(percent)', 'count' => $countColumn, 'average' => $percentColumn]);

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->group('rating_vote.review_id');

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->order('average desc');
```

Thanks